# Have ODM Rule or XOM "know" which environment (prod or non prod) is currently executing rule

Tags: odm, ibm-odm

I would like to use a property or a trick in ODM rules at execution time, to know if the rule is being executed on a prod or non production environment.
I need to pass that information through to XOM java class to load a different properties depending on the environment
I wonder if there is something built in I can use in the rule language to know that

Answer (score 0):

neither the java code (nor the rules) know where they are executed (DEV, QA, PROD). Usually this information is a configuration information.
Maybe you can use that configuration information to populate a Java object and reuse that in the rules.

Best
Emmanuel